# Why is this initdb script not executed when running docker-compose up?

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Docker environment and I can't get the initdb script executed. I'm using PostgreSQL.

So i have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN go build -o rinha ./

CMD ["./rinha"]
```

My docker-compose is writen this way:

```
version: '3'

services:
  rinha:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: rinha
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      DSN: "host=postgres port=5432 user=postgres password=password dbname=rinha sslmode=disable timezone=UTC connect_timeout=5"


  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:14.2'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: rinha
    volumes:
      - ./data/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - ./db-data/postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U "$$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$$POSTGRES_DB"
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 10
```

I've already checked and my initdb is in the correct path and does not have any sintax errors.

But everytime i run docker-compose up --buil -d or anything like that the script is not executed.

Can anyone help me?

PS: i already tried excluding the local db-data but this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

were you able to see any errors in docker compose logs ?

```
docker compose logs postgres
```

or it did not show any errors ?

think usually if the entrypoint scripts are executed, you will see a line like this in the logs

```
postgres-1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

but if you don't see a line like this, I think it means the entrypoint.sh was not triggered, in that case you might want to exclude the volumes directory and re-run docker compose up again, but as you said you already did that and it did not work (so not very sure)

Comment: I did not get any message indicating that the script did get executed. Meanwhile, I tried deleting the volume created on docker-compose up (the ./db-data/postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/) and the script got executed. I don't know why, but it did.

Thank you for your response.